# how to emulate packets using wiresharks info?

Tags: tcp, udp, packet

I just wanted to write a program to show the server-list of teknomw3. I'm not familiar with wireshark or packet-sniffing. I just tried using wireshark and got information.

Below is one of information sent by the master-server to mw3,

[image]

I can clearly see the data sent by the master-server, that contains the data of a dedicated-server.

here's the packet info mw3 sent, before getting the server list,

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to create my own program to get the server list? I know C#, Java. but not an expert.

From where should I start?

Comment: I would love to know the answer to this as well. I hope you get an answer!

Comment: @Psyrus I think need to learn more about packet sniffing